# Facebook Linter: Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named fb:page_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Hi when I run facebook linter on my site (www.mvcc.com.uy) it says:

Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named fb:page_id.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically to get the linter to work properly, you need to add some meta tags in your `<head>`.  Check out more information here:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Also, the Facebook servers only check your site once a day for new meta tags so don't expect the linter to work for a few days after you've added the meta tags.

If you've already done this and you're still experiencing problems - please provide us with examples of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`fb:page_id` isn't required for Open Graph pages.